# Configuring sshguard for more than one port

Tags: 20.04, firewall, sshd

I am running `sshd` on more than one port, say `22` and `2222`.

I have installed `sshguard` to the system. How can I configure it to guard against attacks on all the ports defined in `sshd`'s configuration?

Note: I am using UFW and the *ssh* ports are open to public IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the ports to be filtered are defined in the line ending with `sshguard` in the file `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```
$ sudo grep -C1 :sshguard /etc/ufw/before.rules
```

```
# hand off control for sshd to sshguard
:sshguard - [0:0]
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j sshguard
```

So, editing the line ending with `sshguard`, like this, should do the trick:

```
-A ufw-before-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,2222 -j sshguard
```

---

However, I haven't found a similar entry for IPv6.